# SVM: Choosing Support Vector Machine regression termination criterion tolerence in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, scikit-learn

I am using `sklearn.svr` with the `RBF` kernel on an 80k-size dataset with 20+ variables. I was wondering how to choose the termination parameter `tol`. I ask because the regression does not seem to converge for certain combinations of C and gamma (2+ days before I give up). Interestingly, it converges after less than 10 minutes for certain combinations with an average run-time of approximately an hour.

Is there some sort of rule of thumb for setting this parameter? Perhaps a relationship to the standard deviation or expected value of the forecast?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried the Nystroem approximation and it seemed almost as bad as the purely linear regression, and since precision is what I'm looking for, I ended up going for sub-samples, which seem to approximate the large data set very well.

Comment: Ps: I'm still curious about the tolerance.

Answer (score 5):

Mike's answer is correct: subsampling for grid searching parameter is probably the best strategy to train `SVR` on medium-ish dataset sizes. SVR is not scalable so don't waste your time doing a grid search on the full dataset. Try on 1000 random sub samples, then 2000 and then 4000. Each time find the optimal values for C and gamma and try to guess how they evolve whenever you double the size of the dataset.

Also you can approximate the true SVR solution with the [Nystroem kernel approximation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/kernel_approximation.html#nystroem-kernel-approx) and a linear regressor model such as SGDRegressor, LinearRegression, LassoCV or ElasticNetCV. RidgeCV is likely not to improve upon LinearRegression in the `n_samples >> n_features` regime.

Finally, do not forget to scale your input data by putting a `MinMaxScaler` or a `StandardScaler` before the `SVR` model in a `Pipeline`.

I would also try `GradientBoostingRegressor` models (although completely unrelated to SVR).

Comment: would you happen to have any remarks/tips specifically on the 'tol' variable as per the OP's question?

Comment: You can try to loosen the tolerance to speed up learning but in case of bad predictive performance it's harder to tell whether this is caused by premature stopping (bad optimization) or bad learning hyperparameters.

Answer (score 4):

You may have seen the scikit learn [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html#example-svm-plot-rbf-parameters-py) for the RBF function. Considering what C and gamma actually do and the fact that the SVR training time is at worst quadratic in the number of samples, I would try training first on a small subset of the data. By first getting a result for all parameter settings and then scaling up the amount of training data used, you might find you actually only need a small sample of the data to get results very close to the full set.

This is the advice I was given by my MSc project supervisor recently, as I had the exact same problem. I found that out of a set of 120k examples with 250 features I only needed around 3000 samples to get within 2% of the error of the full set models.

Sorry this isn't answering your question directly, but I thought it might help.

Answer (score 4):

You really shouldn't use `SVR` on large data sets: its training algorithm takes between quadratic and cubic time. `sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor` can fit a linear regression on such datasets without trouble, so try that instead. If linear regression won't hack it, transform your data with a [kernel approximation](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.com/2012/12/kernel-approximations-for-efficient.html) before feeding it to `SGDRegressor` to get a linear-time approximation of an RBF-SVM.